# What is the propagation delay for Shopify's CDN?

Tags: shopify, assets, cdn

I am trying to make changes on a Shopify site, and have inserted a C-style comment at the end of the stylesheet. When I checked immediately after, the comment was not visible.

I am presently unsure whether I've made a change to the actual site that is live, or another version that is available to the administrator but not the current live site.

How long does it normally take for updates to the main .scss file to propagate through Shopify's CDN?

Alternately, is there another way I should be telling if I am editing the present live version of the site or some other copy?

Answer (score 0):

You can always bust your cache asset just by appending a time stamp to it if you want to ensure you're looking at new content. Just uploading a new stylesheet might not immediately render you a non-cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Update / answer to my question:

I didn't see my test addition to the stylesheet because I was changing something other than the active theme.

When I made test additions to the active theme's stylesheet, my changes were instantly live.

So Shopify may use a CDN, but they've set things up so I don't have to wait a quota of time to see a change on the website.